# Ruby on Rails Functional Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

i've this code :

```
  def test_create
    assert_difference('Comment.count') do
      post :create, :comment => {:comment => 'Comment'}
      assert_not_nil assigns(:comment)
      assert_equal assigns(:comment).comment, "Comment"
      assert_equal assigns(:comment).valid?, true
    end
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirected_to article_path(assigns(:comment))
    assert_equal flash[:notice], 'Comment was successfully created.'
  end
```

And try to testing it, but it return :

```
    test_create(CommentsControllerTest) [test/functional/comments_controller_test.rb:5]:
<nil> expected to not be nil.
```

What's wrong with this code? Please help me i'm newbie on Rails

Answer (score 0):

It says " expected to not be nil". So it's complaining at the assert_not_nil line, where you check the comment variable.

You have a problem with that variable. Maybe it does not exist.